# convert the input table to mentioned output table by using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert the input table to mentioned output table by using SQL statement, Can anyone please help me on this.

Input table

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| start_value | end_value | interval |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|           0 |       120 |       10 |
|           1 |       150 |       50 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

OUTPUT

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
|     start_value | end_value | next_start_value |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
|               0 |       120 |                0 |
|               0 |       120 |               10 |
|               0 |       120 |               20 |
|               0 |       120 |               30 |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: When does the '10' interval end in the output?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? This is not a code writing service. You might also want to explain your output a little better and how it relates to the input.

Comment: @Daniel Marcus Looks like it would be tied to the 'end_value' field.

Comment: So in this case you'd iterate by 10s up until next_start_value=120? Then what?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for replying when it reaches to end_value. total 13 record it will generate as output.

Comment: How is it converted?

Comment: start_value+interval

Comment: I see ok - ill work on this for you

Comment: So, to sum up, you defined the input data quite OK. The problem was with stating what you want to achieve (e.g. producing the list of increments starting with `start_value`, using 'interval` as step, and ending with `end_value`) and giving a good example of expected result (the one you've given is incomplete). You still have not stated what is the expected result when while iterating, we do not exactly hit the `end_value`, as with the `start_value` of 1 and `interval` of 50, we do not hit the `end_value` of 150 - is the expected list of values 1, 51, 101 or should it also contain 151 (or 150)?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99982f/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE input ( start_value, end_value, "INTERVAL" ) AS
SELECT 0, 120, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 150, 50 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH output ( rn, start_value, end_value, "INTERVAL", next_start_value ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, i.*, start_value FROM input i
UNION ALL
  SELECT rn,
         start_value,
         end_value,
         "INTERVAL",
         next_start_value + "INTERVAL"
  FROM   output
  WHERE  next_start_value + "INTERVAL" <= end_value
)
SELECT start_value, end_value, next_start_value
FROM   output
ORDER BY rn, next_start_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99982f/3/0)**:

```
| START_VALUE | END_VALUE | NEXT_START_VALUE |
|-------------|-----------|------------------|
|           0 |       120 |                0 |
|           0 |       120 |               10 |
|           0 |       120 |               20 |
|           0 |       120 |               30 |
|           0 |       120 |               40 |
|           0 |       120 |               50 |
|           0 |       120 |               60 |
|           0 |       120 |               70 |
|           0 |       120 |               80 |
|           0 |       120 |               90 |
|           0 |       120 |              100 |
|           0 |       120 |              110 |
|           0 |       120 |              120 |
|           1 |       150 |                1 |
|           1 |       150 |               51 |
|           1 |       150 |              101 |
```

Answer (score 0):

As [MTD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142677/5853770) does not actually fully meet the expected output structure, based on his/hers approach, I'd suggest this altered answer:

```
WITH output (start_value, end_value, "INTERVAL", next_start_value) AS (
  SELECT start_value, end_value, "INTERVAL", start_value AS next_start_value
    FROM input
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_value,
         end_value,
         "INTERVAL",
         next_start_value + "INTERVAL" AS next_start_value
    FROM output
   WHERE next_start_value + "INTERVAL" <= end_value
)
SELECT start_value, end_value, next_start_value
  FROM output
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

**EDIT**: Adding the query result:

```
START_VALUE | END_VALUE | NEXT_START_VALUE
------------+-----------+-----------------
          0 |       120 |                0
          0 |       120 |               10
          0 |       120 |               20
          0 |       120 |               30
          0 |       120 |               40
          0 |       120 |               50
          0 |       120 |               60
          0 |       120 |               70
          0 |       120 |               80
          0 |       120 |               90
          0 |       120 |              100
          0 |       120 |              110
          0 |       120 |              120
          1 |       150 |                1
          1 |       150 |               51
          1 |       150 |              101
```

[This is the SQL Fiddle for it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb7b4/2/0)